# How do I return to the default output (cell output) in Google Colab? Reassign sys.stdout to sys.__stdout__ doesn't seem to be working

Tags: python, io, printf, google-colaboratory, stdout

I'm trying to save results from printing the help of a function in a file, instead of presenting them on the cell output in Google Colab.

My code is below:

```
import sys
import io

def capture_help_to_buffer(obj):
    output_buffer = io.StringIO()
    sys.stdout = output_buffer

    try:
        help(obj)
    except:
        pass

    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
    return output_buffer.getvalue()

# Example usage
help_output = capture_help_to_buffer(list)
print(help_output)
```

My problem is: after running this code, `print` starts returns nothing. In other words: it seems that the reassiging of `sys.stdout` to its supposedly default value (`sys.__stdout__`) is not working.

My question: to what value should I reassign `sys.stdout` so `print` will return to its normal behavior (presenting its output in Google Colab's cell's output)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve this with `contextlib.redirect_stdout`, like so:

```py
import sys
import io

from contextlib import redirect_stdout


def capture_help_to_buffer(obj):
    output_buffer = io.StringIO()

    with redirect_stdout(output_buffer):
        try:
            help(obj)
        except:
            pass

    return output_buffer.getvalue()
```

This creates a context in which `stdout` is redirected then restored when you exit the code block.

Here's the `contextlib.redirect_stdout` documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout